# STDistance – Calculates distance between two objects

Tags: sql-server, geography, sqlgeography, geographic-distance

I try to calculate the distance between two objects.

```
declare @p1 geography
declare @p2 geography
SELECT @p1 = WKT from tbl_1 where loc = "school"
SELECT @p2 = WKT from tbl_2 where loc = "school"
select round(@p1.STDistance(@p2)/1000,0) Distance_KM
```

But i get an error for the column `loc`

> Invalid column name

This column exists and data type is `geography`.

Column `WKT` is populated using:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[lbl_1]
SET [WKT] = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
GO
```

What's wrong ??

Comment: Do you mean that `loc` column of geography type and not `VARCHAR`

Comment: also do both your tables `tbl_1`  and `tbl_2` have a column `loc`?

Comment: What is `"school"` a string literal or a column? sql server is treating it as a column which is why I think you are getting your error. Try this `declare @p1 geography select 1 WHERE @p1 = "school"`

Comment: Got it. The string literal 'school' is between single quotes and not double qoutes :-((

Comment: what you are trying to do is fundamentally incorrect. how can `'school'` a string be equal to a `GEOGRAPHY` type column `loc`??

Comment: column 'loc' is data type char(15) and WKT is data type geography

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string literal is incorrect.

For SQL, you want single quotes, iow `'school'` and not `"school"`.

SQL treats it as a column and not a string literal.

Comment: even if OP uses string literal with a geography type, it will not work. `Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals equal to, type equals geography.`

Comment: @ughai: Who says `loc` is of type geography? `WKT` is.

Comment: check his question and his comment

Comment: @ughai: Based on his/her response, the information provided in the comment/question is not correct.

Comment: It should be wrong but OP has stated loc is geography twice. once in the question and once in his comment.

Comment: @ughai: I realize that, but it does not make logical sense ;p